# id parameter in get request

Tags: django, python-requests

I am new to Django and a small detail has been bothering me.I have an api endpoint that returns the details of one patient. I have made a successful get request and tested on postman. It returns data for a particular patient with id = 996(I have hard coded the id). But I need to set it so it can pick the id from params in postman instead of the hard coded one here. How can I set params and append them on the url so that I use the id fed in postman instead of hard coding? Kindly assist

**views.py**

```
class PatientDetailsView(GenericAPIView):
authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

@classmethod
@encryption_check
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    try:
        result = {}
        auth = cc_authenticate()
        res = getPatientDetails(auth["key"], id)
        result = res
       
        return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            
    except Exception as e:
        error = getattr(e, "message", repr(e))
        result["errors"] = error
        result["status"] = "error"

    return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**api_service.py**

```
def getPatientDetails(auth, id):

print("getting patientdetails from Callcenter")

try:
    print(auth)
    # print(url)
    id= 996
    
    headers = {
                "Authorization": f'Token {auth}'
    }
    url = f'{CC_URL}/patients/v1/details/?id={id}'
    print(url)
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   
    print("returning patientdetails response",  res.status_code)

    return res.json()

except ConnectionError as err:
    print("connection exception occurred")
    print(err)

    return err
```

**urls.py**

```
 path("details/", views.PatientDetailsView.as_view(), name="patient_info"),
```

Comment: you can define urls like this `path('details/<int:pid>/', PatientDetailsView.as_view())` to capture the incoming id in the url.

Comment: the above or if you want to use a get parameter `request.GET.get('<parmater_name>')`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: @VishalSingh That wont work coz am trying to pass the id as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I needed

```
id = request.GET.get('<id>')
```